# Power BI translating a sql query to filters

Tags: powerbi

I was wondering if this is possible in Power BI, I am extremely new to this and I am trying to relate how a sql query can translate in to a power bi report.

```
SELECT
    expiresDate,
    Name,
    Addr,
    ValidFrom,
    ValidTo,
    ChildName,
    ChildValidFrom,
    ChildValidTo,
    RecValidFrom,
    RecValidTo
FROM Table
WHERE expiresDate Between <date1> and <date2>
AND <Date3> BETWEEN ValidFrom AND ValidTo
AND <Date3> BETWEEN ValidFrom AND ValidTo
AND <Date3> BETWEEN ValidFrom AND ValidTo
```

A brief explanation. The report is for 3 months in advance. So in August the report is for September <date1 = 01/09/2021) and October (date2 = 31/10/2021) data. However the data can change on a daily basis. So this depends on Date3 which could be any day in August.

I have created a table that is a calendar and has the additional columns that calculate the start and end dates from a particular date. I just can't work out how to relate this to the dataset which is the query without the WHERE. I would then want the filters to be able to determine the result. Ultimately as I have it at present a single date that will then get the dates from the start and end dates as described earlier. Or display by range using the latest iteration of the record to display.

For example, First part of table

| expiresDate | AccNo | Name | Addr | ValidFrom | ValidTo | ChildName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 1 | Robert | 1 Here | 2019-01-01 | 2021-08-16 | Cheese |
| 2021-10-01 | 1 | Robert | 1 Here | 2019-01-01 | 2021-08-16 | Rhubarb |
| 2021-10-01 | 1 | Bob | 1 Here | 2021-08-17 | 2020-08-23 | Rhubarb |

Second half of table

| ChildValidFrom | ChildValidTo | RecValidFrom | RecValidTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | 2021-08-10 | 2019-19-01 | 2020-12-31 |
| 2021-08-11 | 2021-08-23 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-08-15 |
| 2021-08-11 | 2021-08-23 | 2021-08-16 | 2020-08-23 |

The table is a view which has squashed the data to unique records and when the changes occurred. The dataset is considerably lower, a record count from 10m to 54k.

The requirement is that all To - From dates are within the date specified. Either being a date in the calendar that is entered as a filter... or today.

The report would bring out all records that have an expiryDate greater than 1 calendar month of the date, and less than 3 calendar months. I am just using August dates for the example so this would be from the 01/09/2021 - 31/10/2021.

If I use date 2021-08-01.

In my example there are 3 results for AccNo 1, but Only 1 should be displayed.

If I use the date 2021-08-01 the first row would be displayed.
If I use the date 2021-08-12 the second row should displayed.
If I use the date 2021-08-23 the third row should displayed.

Because the date used should fall between the date range of all 3 criteria

ValidFrom - ChildValidTo
ChildValidFrom - ChildValidTo
RecValidFrom - RecValidTo

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is extremely frustrating, but I can understand that if this is possibly that this would make a nice visual for the users to check through their data based on entering a date.

Many thanks

Comment: Add sample data and your expected output from them.

Comment: @mkRabbani. I can't get the top half of the table to display, though it does in the preview. But I hope this helps explain the problem that I am having.

Comment: @mkRabbani. Hi I have been looking at a reply for a previous question that you helped on. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63236122/power-bi-select-slicer-date-between-2-columns). I think this is at least part of he solution that I require. Which is kind of what I have done on this, but that doesn't work. I was wondering about the final step, as it is the most important part. I've tried to do this, but it doesn't work for me. I was wondering if you could explain this. Many thanks.